# Seems the Sidebar Has Lost Some Sections

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin, sidebar, featured-questions

What has happened to

- Featured On Meta
- Hot Meta Posts

?

[image: Site sidebar missing the "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" sections]

Comment: Situation is same across network. See this post on metaSE: [Hot meta posts section is no more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389886)

Comment: We're investigating an issue with Redis that also affects bulletins. They'll likely come in and out while we're looking into it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks for your patience, the issue should be resolved now.

I unfortunately don't have any particularly juicy details to share about the underlying cause, but the short version is that we had a route that was hitting Redis when we didn't expect it to hit Redis and that ended up creating too much load in combination with our hourly scheduled routes.

As far as the bulletins go, they should self-correct over the next hour or two across the network.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt handling of this, and for the even-prompter response to the initial report in order to address the unfortunate optics. This kind of thing is excellent for building trust. Much appreciated.

Comment: The bug seems to be back, at least on Stack Overflow. :-( Unfortunately, it's a weekend, so you probably aren't around to kick Redis again, but you might want to give it a look when you are next available.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Yeah, I was unavailable most of Saturday, unfortunately, and just saw this now. Looks like it's back to normal, though, so hopefully it can stay that way.